# Why am I getting distorted audio through my piano when recording in Audacity using an aux cable?

Tags: audio, recording

I am having a problem regarding audio recording quality with a line using my Yamaha P-120 piano. I am getting a weird distortion in my audio feed upon recording through Audacity.

Here are the details of my current setup:

- **OS:** Linux using Alsa.
- **Hardware:** 1/8 to 1/4 adapter, auxiliary cord, Yamaha P-120.
- **Software:** Audacity.

I’ve tested the cables and adapters, used different recording mediums, reinstalled audacity, and restarted my computer but I can’t figure out what the problem is. The computer is getting the feed just at an extremely bad quality. It sounds like I am going past the input level despite software indicated normal levels.

Comment: Does your piano have a volume control? Clipping might well occur at the very moment the sound is digitized. So try turning down the input volume.

Comment: Tried audio...didn't help. Like I said, the input levels look fine and it doesn't look like its clipping

Comment: Nevermind, it was clipping. Thanks. Turns out that while the output levels and input levels looked fine, it still decided to clip on me. I'm a little confused as to why but it is all fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer?  That will help others with a similar problem.  Accepting your own answer will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by going to the microphone settings and disabling both:

- Windows enhancements
- Microphone boost

[image]

[image]